# Compiled Python Script Wouldn't Work

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gdal, fiona

I designed a small tool for my colleagues with Python, and I tried to compile it with PyInstaller to distribute. This is what happened when I ran the executable:

[image]

And below are messages I received when compiling it:

```
C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor>C:\Python36-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe Controller.py
711 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
711 INFO: Python: 3.6.2
712 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
719 INFO: wrote C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\Controller.spec
720 INFO: UPX is not available.
726 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Tiancheng\\Scripts\\UT Extractor', 'C:\\Tiancheng\\Scripts\\UT Extractor']
726 INFO: checking Analysis
726 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
726 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
730 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
738 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7436 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
7447 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python36-32\python.exe
7475 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python.exe
7496 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python.exe
7512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python.exe
7527 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python.exe
7543 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python.exe
7747 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7762 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7779 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7794 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7811 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7831 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7850 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7866 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7891 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7911 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7927 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7943 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\python36.dll
7967 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
7983 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
8002 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
8018 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
8033 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
8042 INFO: Caching module hooks...
8049 INFO: Analyzing C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\Controller.py
11313 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
14389 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
14396 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
19102 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
20074 INFO: Loading module hooks...
20074 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
20087 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
20213 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
20229 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
20350 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-osgeo.py"...
20382 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
20964 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
21056 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
21520 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-psycopg2.py"...
21528 WARNING: Hidden import "mx.DateTime" not found!
21528 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
21536 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
21546 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
21554 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
21663 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
22377 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py"...
22538 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
22552 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
22726 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-shapely.py"...
22836 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
22849 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-unidecode.py"...
24992 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
25262 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
25332 WARNING: library geos_c.dll required via ctypes not found
25373 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
25382 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
25395 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
25420 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_osgeo.py'
25428 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
25456 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
25514 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
25543 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
25581 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
25603 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
25626 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
25711 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25733 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25759 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25781 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25809 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25861 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25884 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
25926 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
25956 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
25980 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
26031 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
26061 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
26134 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
26155 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
26184 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
26211 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
26271 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
26300 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
26325 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
26373 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
26397 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
26461 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26483 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26506 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26528 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26559 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26585 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26606 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
26649 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
26676 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
26701 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
26766 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
26805 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
26908 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
26934 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
26997 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27019 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27041 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27066 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27087 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27108 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27129 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll
27220 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27242 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27263 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27289 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27317 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27341 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27364 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos.dll
27413 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
27439 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
27490 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27534 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27558 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27589 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27615 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27635 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27656 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
27821 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27856 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27881 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27904 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27930 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28039 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28075 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28120 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
28147 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
28172 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
28203 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
28237 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
28258 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
28280 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
28304 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
28326 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
28348 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
-----------------------------a whole bunch of similar warnings -----------------------------
47101 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\MSVCP140.dll
47122 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\MSVCP140.dll
47146 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\MSVCP140.dll
47146 INFO: Looking for eggs
47147 INFO: Using Python library c:\python36-32\python36.dll
47148 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
47167 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\build\Controller\warnController.txt
47347 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\build\Controller\xref-Controller.html
47444 INFO: checking PYZ
47444 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
47445 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\build\Controller\out00-PYZ.pyz
49113 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\build\Controller\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
49153 INFO: checking PKG
49153 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
49154 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
49212 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
49222 INFO: Bootloader c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
49222 INFO: checking EXE
49223 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
49223 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
49224 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Tiancheng\Scripts\UT Extractor\build\Controller\Controller.exe
49446 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
49459 INFO: checking COLLECT
49459 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
49461 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
55290 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

An engineer in the company took a brief look for me, she said it is probably due to the version of GDAL and Fiona on my machine are not compatible, but she is too busy to help with the rest.

I am using **Python 3.6**, with **GDAL 2.2.4** and **Fiona 1.7.11 post1**, both installed through wheels downloaded from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

The modules I imported within my functions.py are as below:

```
import psycopg2
import pymysql
import re
import time, datetime
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Point
import unidecode
```

I couldn't find similar problems anywhere.

Added: I checked I do have pypiwin32 installed. I forgot to mention that I do not have Python in my system variable (because I need to keep Python 27 to make Arcpy work), nor do I have GDAL in the path, does this matter? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: You have multiple warnings about win32com not being found. Maybe check that first?

Comment: Hi @mbrig, I checked, I already have pypiwin32 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up pip and start using Conda, when I installed the mentioned modules through Conda they all seems to work fine together.

Answer (score 3):

When reading this output its best to look for the first error thrown.

Try `pip install pypiwin32`